# Grails and spring security how to get composite id in controller?

Tags: java, grails, spring-security

This is the SecUserSecRole class in grails

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder

class SecUserSecRole implements Serializable {

SecUser secUser
SecRole secRole

static mapping = {
id composite: ['secUser', 'secRole'] <----- this
version false
}

boolean equals(other) {
    if (!(other instanceof SecUserSecRole)) {
        return false
    }

    other.secUser?.id == secUser?.id &&
        other.secRole?.id == secRole?.id
}

int hashCode() {
    def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
    if (secUser) builder.append(secUser.id)
    if (secRole) builder.append(secRole.id)
    builder.toHashCode()
}

static SecUserSecRole get(long secUserId, long secRoleId) {
    find 'from SecUserSecRole where secUser.id=:secUserId and secRole.id=:secRoleId',
        [secUserId: secUserId, secRoleId: secRoleId]
}

static SecUserSecRole create(SecUser secUser, SecRole secRole, boolean flush = false) {
    new SecUserSecRole(secUser: secUser, secRole: secRole).save(flush: flush, insert: true)
}

static boolean remove(SecUser secUser, SecRole secRole, boolean flush = false) {
    SecUserSecRole instance = SecUserSecRole.findBySecUserAndSecRole(secUser, secRole)
    if (!instance) {
        return false
    }

    instance.delete(flush: flush)
    true
}

static void removeAll(SecUser secUser) {
    executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM SecUserSecRole WHERE secUser=:secUser', [secUser: secUser]
}

static void removeAll(SecRole secRole) {
    executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM SecUserSecRole WHERE secRole=:secRole', [secRole: secRole]
}

}
```

and this is the autogenerated controller:

```
class SecUserSecRoleController {

static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]

def index() {
    redirect(action: "list", params: params)
}

def list(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    [secUserSecRoleInstanceList: SecUserSecRole.list(params), secUserSecRoleInstanceTotal: SecUserSecRole.count()]
}

def create() {
    [secUserSecRoleInstance: new SecUserSecRole(params)]
}

def save() {
    def secUserSecRoleInstance = new SecUserSecRole(params)
    if (!secUserSecRoleInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "create", model: [secUserSecRoleInstance: secUserSecRoleInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'secUserSecRole.label', default: 'SecUserSecRole'), secUserSecRoleInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "show", id: secUserSecRoleInstance.id)
}

def show(Long id) {
    def secUserSecRoleInstance = SecUserSecRole.get(id)
    if (!secUserSecRoleInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'secUserSecRole.label', default: 'SecUserSecRole'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    [secUserSecRoleInstance: secUserSecRoleInstance]
}

def edit(Long id) {
    def secUserSecRoleInstance = SecUserSecRole.get(id)
    if (!secUserSecRoleInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'secUserSecRole.label', default: 'SecUserSecRole'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    [secUserSecRoleInstance: secUserSecRoleInstance]
}

def update(Long id, Long version) {
    def secUserSecRoleInstance = SecUserSecRole.get(id)
    if (!secUserSecRoleInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'secUserSecRole.label', default: 'SecUserSecRole'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    if (version != null) {
        if (secUserSecRoleInstance.version > version) {
            secUserSecRoleInstance.errors.rejectValue("version", "default.optimistic.locking.failure",
                      [message(code: 'secUserSecRole.label', default: 'SecUserSecRole')] as Object[],
                      "Another user has updated this SecUserSecRole while you were editing")
            render(view: "edit", model: [secUserSecRoleInstance: secUserSecRoleInstance])
            return
        }
    }

    secUserSecRoleInstance.properties = params

    if (!secUserSecRoleInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "edit", model: [secUserSecRoleInstance: secUserSecRoleInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'secUserSecRole.label', default: 'SecUserSecRole'), secUserSecRoleInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "show", id: secUserSecRoleInstance.id)
}

def delete(Long id) {
    def secUserSecRoleInstance = SecUserSecRole.get(id)
    if (!secUserSecRoleInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'secUserSecRole.label', default: 'SecUserSecRole'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    try {
        secUserSecRoleInstance.delete(flush: true)
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'secUserSecRole.label', default: 'SecUserSecRole'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
    }
    catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'secUserSecRole.label', default: 'SecUserSecRole'), id])
        redirect(action: "show", id: id)
    }
}
}
```

This means the `show(Long id)` `edit(Long id)` `update(Long id, Long version)` and `delete(Long id)` wont work. Since the id is composite, how do you get it in the controller?

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious and it's a simple fix, so I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction! Im still learning how to code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

again :), this domain class is generated by spring-security-plugin and its use isn't to be exposed directly to web. Normally grails scaffolding isn't applied to this domain class, but only to user and role domain class with some correction. If your need is to administrate roles,users and relations between users and roles you can use spring-security-ui-plugin. With this plugin you have a group of views/controllers that help you to manage spring-secuirity-plugin. At least if you want to create you personal web interface, whereas the plugin is opensource you could see how the controllers, which are used in this plugin, work. Bye

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this case it should be something like (for show() method):

```
def show(Long secUserId, Long secRoleId) {
    def secUserSecRoleInstance = SecUserSecRole.get(secUserId, secRoleId)
    if (!secUserSecRoleInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'secUserSecRole.label', default: 'SecUserSecRole'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    [secUserSecRoleInstance: secUserSecRoleInstance]
}
```